# Why does deep cloning my state cause ngrx to go into an infinite loop, constantly calling my reducer?

Tags: lodash, infinite-loop, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

We had the following ngrx reducer, but added a nested object to our state (structure: `settings: { a: boolean, b: string }`), so decided to use lodash’s `cloneDeep(obj)` instead of the `...obj` spread operator to ensure our state is immutable, as per the second note in the official docs’ [“Creating the Reducer Function”](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function) section:

> The spread operator only does shallow copying and does not handle
>   deeply nested objects. You need to copy each level in the object to
>   ensure immutability. There are libraries that handle deep copying
>   including [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer).

```
// before:
export function reducer(state: MyState = initialState, action: Actions): MyState {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case MY_TASK: {
      return {
        ...state,
        prop1: action.payload.prop,
        prop2: initialState.anotherProp
      };
    }
    // ..
  }
}
```

When we changed that to the following, ngrx kept calling the `reducer()` method, effectively blocking (crashing) the browser:

```
// after - causes infinite loop
import * as _ from 'lodash';
// ..

export function reducer(oldState: MyState = initialState, action: Actions): MyState {
  function nextState(stateChanges?: (MyState) => void): MyState {
    const draftState: MyState = _.cloneDeep(oldState);
    if (stateChanges) {
      stateChanges(draftState);
    }
    return draftState;
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case MY_TASK: {
      return nextState(s => {
        s.prop1 = action.payload.prop;
        s.prop2 = initialState.anotherProp;
      });
    }
    // ..
  }
}
```

`stateChange`doesn't even touch the new nested *additional state properties* (i.e. the `settings` object), only the flat ones (`prop1, prop2`) we had previously. `settings` is, however, part of `oldState` and thus passed to lodash's `cloneDeep()`.

**Any idea why changing the returned state** (i.e. using `_.deepClone(state)` instead of the spread `...state` operator) **would have that effect - and how to stop it?**

We are using `@ngrx/entity`, so the state is extending `EntityState<MyState>`. I unserstand that [the library's entity functinos return a new state](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods) (or "the same state if no changes were made"), and that *[additional properties](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/recipes/additional-state-properties#additional-entity-state-properties-update)* like our new nested `settings` object can be added to the state but that
"[t]hese properties must be updated manually" - which I take to mean I have to clone them myself.

Is the mistake that we attempt to clone the entire state (which extends `EntityState<T>`), not just the *additional properties*?

The only changes between the working and the broken code were made in the `reducer()` method, so I don't think we are accidentally firing any new event we didn't fire before, which would usually associated with causing an infinite loop...

Comment: It seems like something is dispatching an action whenever a specific part of the state changes. Since you are cloning everything, the state always changes, which causes an action to be dispatched, and so on...

Comment: I've added breakpoints on every event dispatcher I could find in our code, but so far none fires during that loop. Is there a way to find out what exactly triggers this?

Answer (score 1):

`_.cloneDeep` is the worst case scenario for `ngrx` because it means that everything has been touched in the store and it triggers all selectors again.

From the described error I can assume that you have a `selector` that causes `dispatch` in some case and because the dispatched `action` caused `_.cloneDeep` the selector is triggered again that causes `dispatch` etc...